# BIOS scans hard drive before boot, prolonging boot time

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I have an SSD and a hard drive hooked up to my PC.
I have Arch Linux installed onto my SSD, and the BIOS is configured to do nothing but boot to the SSD via UEFI first. However, the BIOS decides to start reading my hard drive for a very long time (systemd tells me around 45 seconds in firmware) and I'm not sure why.

When I unplug my Hard Drive, it suddenly boots *very* quickly.

If it helps, the drive is formatted in NFTS with GPT partitioning.

Thanks!

Comment: I have 3 UEFI / GPT regular machines here and a 4th I am setting up. No perceptible delay in booting. Is your OS compatible with UEFI and GPT?

Comment: @John ArchLinux definitely is and has been for a decade or more. ;)

Comment: It is compatible, I boot via UEFI. I forgot to add that in my original statement, so I'll update it

Comment: Get the hard drive Manufacturer's drive test app and test for errors.

Comment: My hard drive has no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my BIOS would look through all the files on the root of the hard drive. Moving these files into a folder fixed the issue, and my PC boots up fine now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what machine make and model? This really interests me and sounds like a BIOS setting of some kind.

Comment: It's an Intel Desktop Board DH61CR